# How do I know if my cast is diverse enough or too diverse?

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, characters, gender

Basically, I am writing a story and I want to know if the characters are diverse enough or too diverse. If I just state the characters' races, sexualities, etc, it might seem forced but I didn't really focus on it much, they just are that way. A lot of the characters come from different places, so there isn't really one place for me to google the demographics of, but they are mostly from various states in the US and an island that I made up. I'm not going to say my characters specifically because I would like more general advice for other future stories as well. I'm mostly worried about my story not being diverse enough, because, it is possible for something to be too diverse, but I figure as long as most of the cast isn't the same thing, it'll be alright. And a lot of people are underrepresented, so I'm more focused on that.

Most of my characters are some form of lgbt+, but I'm not very worried about that because most stories are pretty much all straight so it wouldn't be a big deal. it's not like I stop every 2 pages to mention it. And I made sure to make them a mix of different sexualities. i tend to just automatically make everyone bi or something but im working on it

I'm sorry if this explanation was too long! But I would really appreciate answers for this because I couldn't find much about this. Or if you could mention websites that talk about this, that would be great too! So yeah. (:

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE kaleidoscope, glad to have you here.  To learn more about us, check out our [tour] and [help].

Comment: Too diverse for whom? It is pointless to ask if a story has too much or too little of something without specifying a standard of measurement. It is like asking whether explicit depictions of sex are acceptable in a novel without specifying genre or age range. For a picture book or a spicy romance? The question is unanswerable without specifying an audience.

Comment: "If I need a justification I'll just say how they're in a drama club" - you don't need to justify the existence of LGBT+ individuals in your story, just as we don't need to justify our existence in real life. We don't *need* a reason to exist, we just *do*.

Answer (score 10):

Welcome to the SE.

**What is the *story?***

The gayest drag queen in the world would probably watch a story about the Vietnam War as long as it was done well. I'm certain there's at least one or two LGBTQ folks out there who enjoyed *Good Morning Vietnam.*  Everyone was straight in that movie.

**You make your cast what it needs to be to support the story.** Find your story, and make the cast support it.

You seem overly worried about gender and sexual-orientation diversity. That's good to pay attention to, but don't lose track of the story. A huge degree of diversity might be necessary for your story--it depends on what you are writing.

Comment: "I'm certain there's at least one or two LGBTQ folks out there who enjoyed *Good Morning Vietnam*." - I can confirm that I did.

Comment: I agree with DPT’s answer. If I may also add, define diversity through your character’s values and actions regardless of physical appearance and gender.